# Search for specific Char

Tags: typescript, angular

I am learning Angular2. I have one question

I have String array and I printed all of them. however I want to put filter. 
For example: My array is `heroes = ['Windstorm', 'Bombasto', 'Magneta', 'Tornado', 'Windstorming']`. If I write `Wind` result should be 'Windstorm' and 'Windstorming', if I will write `B` it should print `Bombasto` etc.

It will have to search chars in strings.
How can I do it  ? 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried something? you will find a lot of information out there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you want to do that. You can leverage a custom pipe for this:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe {
  transform(arr, value) {
    return arr.filter(elt => {
      // The test can be more advanced and
      // based on regexp
      return elt === value;
    });
  }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
<div *ngFor="#p of heroes | filter:'some value'">
  (...)
</div>
```

You can also leverage a property of the component:

```
<div *ngFor="#p of heroes | filter:someProperty">
  (...)
</div>
```